# keras and sigmoid not predict a right class

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, lstm

I'm trying to fit a model that predict a target class that can be: 0, 1, 2, 3

 during fitting his val_accuracy is: 1.0

but his prediction is like:

> array([[1.2150223e-09]], dtype=float32)

```
X_train.shape 
#(1992, 1, 68)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(1,X_train.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(128, activation="relu",kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(l1=1e-5, l2=1e-4)))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mae', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100,batch_size=16, validation_split=0.1, shuffle=True

X_test = np.expand_dims(X_test,1)
y_test = np.expand_dims(y_test,1)
model.evaluate(X_test,y_test) 
#[0.0010176461655646563, 1.0]

data = np.expand_dims(data, 1)
model.predict(data) #array([[1.2150223e-09]], dtype=float32) <---- here expected was 0, 1, 2 or 3

data.shape #(1, 1, 68)
```

I can't undestand what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Your model has only **one** output however you have **four** classes, so you need to change the last `Dense` layer to `model.add(Dense(4, activation="softmax"))`, `sigmoid` is usually for `binary` classification. In your case, there 4 classes, so `softmax` need to be used. Then you will get probabilities by `probabilities = model.predict(data)` then use
`CATEGORIES[np.argmax(probabilities)]` it gives **predicted class**. By the way, when you want to calculate the loss, use multi-class cross entropy loss: `model.compile(.., loss='categorical_crossentropy', ..)`

```
model.add(Dense(4, activation="softmax"))
probabilities = model.predict(data)
print(CATEGORIES[np.argmax(probabilities)])
```

Comment: with loss='categorical_crossentropy' I get back: ValueError: Shapes (16, 1) and (16, 1, 2) are incompatible in model.fit()

Comment: Did you also change the last layer and activation function?

Comment: with: model.add(Dense(1, activation="softmax")) work, but Accuracy is 0

Comment: You mentioned there are 4 classes. So, final layer output need to be the same. `model.add(Dense(4, activation="softmax"))`